# How to determine the highest middle point of pixels using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Im trying to determine the highest middle point of the white pixles of the below image for the robot to navigate. The codes should display the angle the robot should turn based on the highest middle point.

[image: Image after filtering]

What I want-

[image: What I want is]

Original Image -

[image: Original image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "highest middle point". Can you circle it in your image? Also can you show us the code that you've already tried.

Comment: Plz chq back, i have included the codes as well as two other images for more clarifications

Comment: So you just want the white pixel that is closest to the top of the image?

Comment: Yeap exaclty, i want to get this point for my robot to avoide the obstalces by  moving to the axis of that point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based upon your definition, the "highest middle point" is simply the white pixel that is closest to the top of your image. To get this, you can either use `find` with two outputs to get the row and column or all pixels and then find the one closest to the top.

```
[rows, cols] = find(data == 1);
index = find(rows == min(rows), 1);

row = rows(index);
col = cols(index);
```

Or you could transpose your data and find the location of the first pixel.

```
[col, row] = ind2sub(flip(size(data)), find(data.' == 1, 1));
```

Comment: Excellent, It does exaclty what i want and more for both codes u attached. Thanks a million.